# Error setting property 'd' of RNSVGPath: JSON value of type NSString cannot be converted to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, svg, react-native, svg-path

After updating `react-native-svg`, I started getting this error on a SVG component that worked with the previous versions. The problem is with the `d` attribute of the `Path` element.

```
2017-03-07 17:06:03.253 [error][tid:main][RCTConvert.m:56] Error setting property 'd' of RNSVGPath with tag #35: JSON value 'M 40 60 A 10 10 0 0 0 60 60' of type NSString cannot be converted to NSArray
2017-03-07 17:06:03.368 SampleApp[7590:5782919] -[__NSCFType getPath]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080004280e0
2017-03-07 17:06:03.378 SampleApp[7590:5782919] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType getPath]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080004280e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ae1ad4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010967121e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ae8af04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ada0005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad9fb88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   SampleApp                           0x0000000108bde393 -[RNSVGPath setD:] + 163
    6   SampleApp                           0x0000000108bbbf1b __49-[RCTComponentData propBlockForKey:inDictionary:]_block_invoke.223 + 299
    7   SampleApp                           0x0000000108bbcb40 __49-[RCTComponentData propBlockForKey:inDictionary:]_block_invoke.259 + 720
    8   SampleApp                           0x0000000108bbceb8 __49-[RCTComponentData propBlockForKey:inDictionary:]_block_invoke_2.272 + 40
    9   SampleApp                           0x0000000108b580b3 RCTPerformBlockWithLogFunction + 483
    10  SampleApp                           0x0000000108b5826f RCTPerformBlockWithLogPrefix + 239
    11  SampleApp                           0x0000000108bbce1d __49-[RCTComponentData propBlockForKey:inDictionary:]_block_invoke.267 + 445
    12  SampleApp                           0x0000000108bbd315 __37-[RCTComponentData setProps:forView:]_block_invoke + 181
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ada1dc6 __65-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 102
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ada1cca -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 202
    15  SampleApp                           0x0000000108bbd17f -[RCTComponentData setProps:forView:] + 223
    16  SampleApp                           0x0000000108ba3202 __50-[RCTUIManager createView:viewName:rootTag:props:]_block_invoke + 162
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f3f6978 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f4200cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f4008a4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 406
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010addee49 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ada437d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ada3884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110d21a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010dad9c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    25  SampleApp                           0x0000000108abe5ef main + 111
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f46c68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException2017-03-07 17:06:03.411 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript]
```

The problem appears to be while parsing the `d` attribute in the `getPath` method:
[RNSVGPathParser.m](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/blob/master/ios/Utils/RNSVGPathParser.m)

Versions affected:

`react-native-svg`: `5.1.3`, `4.6.1`, `4.6.0`

`react-native`:`0.42`,`0.41.2`

`react`:`15.4.2`

The problem arised in version `react-native-svg@4.6.0`, probably [this commit](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/commit/293263d6ef2fa93c5e6a860a2ecef72c02845bac).

The line crashing (tested only on iOS):

```
- (void)setD:(RNSVGPathParser *)d
{
    if (d == _d) {
        return;
    }

    [self invalidate];
    _d = d;
    CGPathRelease(_path);
    _path = CGPathRetain([d getPath]);// EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
}
```

The RN component ([based on GitHub sample code](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#svg)):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Svg,{
    Circle,
    Ellipse,
    G,
    LinearGradient,
    RadialGradient,
    Line,
    Path,
    Polygon,
    Polyline,
    Rect,
    Symbol,
    Text,
    Use,
    Defs,
    Stop
} from 'react-native-svg';
export default class SampleSVG extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Svg
        height="100"
        width="100"
      >
        <Rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="black" />
        <Circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" fill="yellow" />
        <Circle cx="40" cy="40" r="4" fill="black" />
        <Circle cx="60" cy="40" r="4" fill="black" />
        <Path d="M 40 60 A 10 10 0 0 0 60 60" stroke="black" />
      </Svg>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: report this issue to there repository.

Answer (score 0):

I used version `4.5.0`, which doesn't have this problem and opened an issue on their repository.